# How would i go about removing this gear cluster?

Tags: sprocket

bike noob here.

Looking to remove this freehub and I don't see the removal tool groves. I’m not sure how to remove this and I can’t seem to find any info on this specific one.

The brand is Suntour [image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Weird lighting in this image. What at first glance appears to be an off-center hex hole is instead the shadow of a hex nut, correct?

Answer (score 6):

You need two chain whips. One to hold the freehub forward and one to unscrew the smallest sprocket, like the old Shimano UG system.

If you only have one chainwhip, you can loosen the sprocket on the bike with a friend putting the tension on the bike chain in the middle of the cassette and you unscrewing with the whip.

Try it and let us know what happens. You won't break anything trying.

This is what you should find underneath:

[image]

The hub is a Suntour Superbe? Or from the MTB range?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it could be a dust cover. In which case you would have to dismantle/remove the axle, and then, gently prise out, with a flat screwdriver, the dust cover. then see what splines are revealed.